# org.json new JSONArray(List) StackOverFlowError with hibernate lazy load

Tags: java, json, hibernate, org.json

I use query.iterate() and add all the entity to an ArrayList for second level cache. But when I change this ArrayList to JSONArray, there  was an StackOverFlowError.

But the strange thing is when I use query.list(). There was nothing wrong!

I have an entity here:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
public class Word {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String literal;
    private String chineseMean;
    //..getter and setter
}
```

and an method of DAO object(use iterate()):

```
public List<Word> getWords(final String wordBook, final int startId,
            final int length) {
        Session session = getSession();
        Query q = session.createQuery("from " + wordBook);
        q.setFirstResult(startId-1);
        q.setMaxResults(length);
        Iterator<Word> iterator = q.iterate();
        List<Word> wordList = new ArrayList<Word>();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            wordList.add(iterator.next());
        }
        return wordList;
    }
```

and use list():

```
public List<Word> getWords_nobuffer(final String wordBook, final int startId,
            final int length) {
        Session session = getSession();
        Query q = session.createQuery("from " + wordBook);
        q.setFirstResult(startId-1);
        q.setMaxResults(length); 
        return q.list();
    }
```

the error place (use iterate()):

```
List<Word> words = worddao.getWords("Word",5, 10);
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(words);//stackoverflowerror!!!!
```

and this way has nothing wrong:

```
List<Word> words = worddao.getWords_nobuffer("Word",5, 10);
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(words);//everything is ok
```

and when I try to use this:

```
List<Word> words = worddao.getWords("Word",5, 10);
List<Word> words2 = worddao.getWords_nobuffer("Word",5, 10);
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(words2);//everything is ok too, all entities are selected from second level cache
```

how did that StackOverFlowError happen?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem..
Entity in hibernate is using lazy mode default.

so in debug mode , we can find the word object was changed to this:

```
{
    id : 0,
    chineseMean : null,
    literal : null,
    handler : JavassistLazyInitializer  // this is key! 
    //all the value of field was put in this object, this object must be used to implement lazy load.
}
```

so, there was something wrong with JSONArray ... (ah.. too complex to find out)

And change the entity to this:

```
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Proxy(lazy=false)//look at here!
public class Word {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String literal;
    private String chineseMean;
    //..getter and setter
}
```

That makes the JSONArray work!